# How to get the length of JSON array?

Tags: json, angular

I have a json url with a response of the following kind

```
[
  {
    "gender": "Female",
    "age": 7,
    "class": 2,
    "subject": [
      "",
      "",
      ""
    ]
  },
  {
    "gender": "Female",
    "age": 8,
    "class": 3,
    "subject": [
      "ab",
      "cd",
      "ef"
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to find the length of this array

so in the angular app I am using

```
export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {

  length: number;
  constructor() { 
    this.length = Object.keys('www.url...').length;
    console.log(length);
  }
```

in .html I have 
`<p>{{ length }}</p>`

I am getting 61 whereas the actual length is 44, but the console on the other hand is showing 0.

Where am I going wrong?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: By length I mean the count.I counted it to be 44.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not mutating this array anywhere?

Comment: @MateuszWitkowski Nope not at all.

Comment: I don't get `this.length = Object.keys('www.url...').length;` ? can you explain more ?

Comment: Is this `www.url..` where you get you json data? If So, you should retrieve the data first then evaluate it's length.

Comment: @Pengyy Yes that is what gives me the json data.

Comment: @SteveDoson currently you are evaluate the length of the url...

Comment: @Pengyy Okay.. can you give a snippet to work around this problem?

Comment: @SteveDoson Refer to `Vivek Doshi`'s answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest method.

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';


export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {

length: number;

constructor(private http: Http){

this.http.request('www.url...',{method:'GET'}).map(response => response.json()).subscribe(result=>{
this.length=result.length;
});

}

}
```

Comment: I am getting an error `Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Response'`

Comment: I am getting error in error TS1005: ')' expected.
error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
error TS1005: '=' expected.
error TS1005: ';' expected.
error TS1005: ';' expected.
error TS1005: ';' expected.
error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

Comment: Sorry a typo. :)  Corrected it. Try now.

Comment: I am still getting the error `Declaration or statement is expected` in the terminal and `Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: pipe is not defined` in the console.

Comment: Yes. I imported `import { map, filter, scan , tap} from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: The error `error TS1005: ')' expected.` is appearing for http.request line, but I can't figure out where is it required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166249/discussion-between-ishara-sandun-and-steve-doson).

Answer (score 0):

> Issue here is you are trying to execute `Object.keys` on `url` and not on
>   `data` , your `url` will be considered as `string`.

Solution is to use `HttpClient` :

```
// First get data from external url and then perform all operation
this.http.get('www.url...').subscribe(data => {
    this.length = data.length;
    console.log(length);
});
```

Comment: I am getting this error `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`